vision Pro vs ios: Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
When targeting iPad from a vision Pro app, I get this error:
Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code

Is problem, that iPad and vision Pro expect different App Icons? Shall I add two different App Icon?
How to handle error?
more:
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
: error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "AppIcon".
/* com.apple.actool.notices */
: warning: Accent color ‘AccentColor’ is not present in any asset catalogs.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/janoskukoda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/i2Elevator-eqbrcwrzxshqggbukgcnihtzrgft/Build/Intermediates.noindex/i2Elevator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/i2Elevator.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code

Here you see standard AppIcon which is compatible with visionPro, but maybe not with iPad?!

